# Windows Server 2008 performance tuning for SQL Server 2008 Enterprise OLAP?

Tags: windows-server-2008, sql-server-2008

Can anyone share your tips and guidance in configuring Windows Server for SQL Server 2008 Enterprise running on 64 GB  RAM with dual quad core Xeon 5670 ?

in the Windows Performance option should I select "programs" of "background services" ?

Thanks

Comment: You've got a long way to go if you're only looking there. That setting gives priorities to Windows Services (of which SQL Server will be just one) over client-driven applications. This is a default and recommended setting for Windows Server and shouldn't change. You're going to need to look at many factors, including storage, RAM configuration, power management and much more.

Answer (score 1):

For SQL Server you can choose Background Services. But there a lot of more setting you need to configure:

- To enable SQL Server to use large
  pages, enable the Lock pages in
  memory user right assignment for the
  account that will run the SQL Server:
  From the Group Policy MMC snap-in
  (Gpedit.msc), navigate to Computer
  Configuration > Windows Settings >
  Security Settings > Local Policies >
  User Rights Assignment. Double-click
  Lock pages in memory and add the
  accounts that have credentials to run
  SQL Server.
- You can set a fixed amount of memory
  for the SQL Server process to use.
  About 3% of the total available
  memory is used for the system, and
  another 1% is used for memory
  management structures. SQL Server 
  can use the rest of available memory,
  but not more.  The following equation
  is available to calculate total
  memory to be used by SQL Server:
  TotalMemory – (1%memory *
  (numa_nodes)) – 3%memory – 1GB memory
- Set CPU affinity for the SQL process:
  Set affinity mask to partition the
  SQL process on specific cores. To set
  affinity on more than 32 logical
  processors, use affinity64 mask.
  Starting with SQL Server 2008 R2, you
  can apply equivalent settings for
  configuring CPU affinity on as many
  as 256 logical processors using the
  ALTER SERVER CONFIGURATION SET
  PROCESS AFFINITY Data Definition
  Language (DDL) TSQL statement as the
  sp_configure affinity mask options
  are announced for deprecation. Use
  the ‘alter server configuration set
  process affinity cpu =’ command to
  set affinity to the desired range of
  processors for each k-group,
  separated by comma.

This are just a few settings, in this whitepaper you will find more settings you need to configure (choose the ones that you find relevant):
[Performance Tuning Guidelines for Windows Server 2008 R2](http://guidovanbrakel.wordpress.com/2010/12/23/performance-tuning-guidelines-for-windows-server-2008-r2/)